# How to check connectivity status of android device?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, interceptor

I have tried so many solutions to get to the answer but nothing helped,
I want your help.
I am developing android app which targets the minimum sdk  of (4.4.4)
and when I am checking the status of the connection it's not working because of deprecated functions.
On the official site of android developers the solution is the same and I could not fix my problem.
Any help ( with code if it is possible )
Thanks.

```
private fun isOnLine(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
            as ConnectivityManager
    val networkInfo  = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ConnectivityManager` if your app targets api 24 or later.

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                val connectivityManager = it.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as
                        ConnectivityManager

                connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object : NetworkCallback() {
                    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                        //take action when network connection is gained
                    }

                    override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
                        //take action when network connection is lost 
                    }
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good enough:

```
    final ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final boolean isNetworkAvailable = connectivity.getActiveNetwork() == null;
```

Comment: this is deprecated on new APIs, use connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback instead